# getting many warnings in edit mode: SendMessage cannot be called during Awake, CheckConsistency, or OnValidate (Cube(Clone): OnDidAddComponent)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want the script to be working in both edit mode and runtime mode,
but I'm getting many warnings with the same message:

```
SendMessage cannot be called during Awake, CheckConsistency, or OnValidate (Cube(Clone): OnDidAddComponent)
UnityEngine.GameObject:AddComponent<CurvedLinePoint> ()
GenerateLines:CreateCubeAtPosition (UnityEngine.Vector3) (at Assets/Scripts/GenerateLines.cs:91)
GenerateLines:GeneratePositions () (at Assets/Scripts/GenerateLines.cs:66)
GenerateLines:GenerateIfNeeded () (at Assets/Scripts/GenerateLines.cs:36)
GenerateLines:OnValidate () (at Assets/Scripts/GenerateLines.cs:23)
```

I saw a long thread about it in Unity's forum, but didn't see any solution. Maybe I need to create an Editor script to make it work also in `edit mode`? I mean Editor script might be the proper way instead using the `[ExecuteInEditMode]` attribute?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class GenerateLines : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Vector3> positions = new List<Vector3>();
    public int amountOfPositions = 30;
    public int minRandRange, maxRandRange;
    public bool randomPositions = false;
    public bool generateNewPositions = false;
    public GameObject cubePrefab; // Assign a prefab with the CubeScript already attached if needed

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        GenerateIfNeeded();
    }

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        GenerateIfNeeded();
    }

    private void GenerateIfNeeded()
    {
        // If we're in play mode, do not execute any further (optional)
        if (Application.isPlaying)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (generateNewPositions || (positions.Count == 0 && amountOfPositions > 0))
        {
            GeneratePositions();
            generateNewPositions = false; // Reset flag to prevent constant regeneration
        }
    }

    private void GeneratePositions()
    {
        // First, destroy all existing children to prevent duplicates
        foreach (Transform child in transform)
        {
            // This line is for edit mode. In play mode, you would use Destroy.
            DestroyImmediate(child.gameObject);
        }
        positions.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfPositions; i++)
        {
            Vector3 position;
            if (randomPositions)
            {
                var randPosX = UnityEngine.Random.Range(minRandRange, maxRandRange);
                var randPosY = UnityEngine.Random.Range(minRandRange, maxRandRange);
                var randPosZ = UnityEngine.Random.Range(minRandRange, maxRandRange);
                position = new Vector3(randPosX, randPosY, randPosZ);
            }
            else
            {
                position = new Vector3(i, i, i);
            }
            positions.Add(position);
            CreateCubeAtPosition(position);
        }
    }

    private void CreateCubeAtPosition(Vector3 position)
    {
        // Create the cube GameObject
        GameObject cube;
        if (cubePrefab != null)
        {
            // Instantiate cube from prefab
            cube = Instantiate(cubePrefab, position, Quaternion.identity, this.transform); // Set the parent to this object's transform
        }
        else
        {
            // Create a new primitive cube
            cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
            cube.transform.position = position;
            cube.transform.localScale = Vector3.one; // Set the scale to 1,1,1

            // Set the parent of the cube to this object's transform
            cube.transform.SetParent(this.transform, false);
        }

        // Add the CurvedLinePoint component to the cube
        cube.AddComponent<CurvedLinePoint>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, you just cannot use `AddComponent` method in the methods like `Awake`, `CheckConsistency`, or `OnValidate` in `edit mode`. I'd consider assigning a `boolean` to `true` in `OnValidate` and calling the desired method in `LateUpdate`, also assigning the boolean back to `false`.

```cs
bool generateIfNeeded = false;

private void OnValidate()
{
    generateIfNeeded = true;
}

private void LateUpdate()
{
    if (generateIfNeeded)
    {
        generateIfNeeded = false;

        GenerateIfNeeded();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your variables my not have been initialized on awake it is a possibility.